# AndroidStudioでdimens.xmlが見えない。

Tags: android-studio

AndroidStudioのProjectツリーの下にdimens.xmlが見えないのですが原因が分かりません。
実際のフォルダ（上の画像）では確かにresフォルダにdimens.xmlは存在しています。
しかし、AndroidStudioから見たProjectのツリー(下の画像)にはdimens.xmlが表示されません。
（このdimens.xmlファイルはテンプレートを作成した際に自動的に作られたようです。）

どこかのファイルで設定する必要がありますか？
[image: Windowsから見たフォルダ下の画像]

[image: AndroidStudioのProjectツリーから見た場合]

Comment: `Sync Project with Gradle Files` や `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` は試しましたか？

Comment: File>Sync Project with Gradle FilesとFile> Invalidate Chaces /Restartを何回か行ったら見えました！

Comment: 何よりです。Android Studio (IntelliJ) って結構、キャッシュが変に悪さしてることが多いんですよね……

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File>Sync Project with Gradle FilesとFile> Invalidate Chaces /Restartを実行することで
AndroidProject側から見ることができました。